# Expandable list issue: setting group textview maxLine and expanding the list same time

Tags: android, expandablelistview

IF there are multiple lines of text in group textview of expandable list then

**what i want is -:** when first list loaded, then only one line appears in every group and when user click on group then all lines in group should be visible + group should be expanded at the same time.

**I have tried to implement** that, But when i click on group view in list, it got expanded but all lines of text in group is not visible but when i click on same group again, all lines are visible.

**This is what, I have tried:**

In group getview method I have set maximum lines of textview to 1.

```
  public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(CorrectqaFragment.this.getActivity());
            textView.setText(getGroup(i).toString());

            textView.setMaxLines(1);    //set maximum lines of textview to 1.
                return textView;
        }
```

elv- refrence to expandable list.

```
 elv.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {

                TextView tv = (TextView)v;
                tv.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE); //set the max lines to max value

                parent.expandGroup(groupPosition); //expand the group

                return true;


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yea, I tried and finally got the answer. actually problem was that every time getGroupView method is called when you expand group in expandable list view and i'am setting maxline 1, that's why on first time click all group text lines are not visible.

So here is solution that worked for me.

```
 public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(CorrectqaFragment.this.getActivity());
        textView.setText(getGroup(i).toString());

      if (b) {
           textView.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
              }else{
            textView.setMaxLines(1);   //set maximum lines of textview to 1.
              } 
            return textView;
    }
```

OnGroupClickListener-:

```
 elv.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, long id) {

            parent.expandGroup(groupPosition); //expand the group

            return true;


        }
    });
```

Explanation:- check group is expanded or not in getGroupView method and set the maxline to textview accordingly as:

```
         if (b) {
           textView.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
              }else{
            textView.setMaxLines(1);   //set maximum lines of textview to 1.
              }
```

where b is boolean returned by isGroupExpand. b = true --> group is expanded vice versa.

and remove the lines from listener those are setting textview max lines.